# C++ Read PE Optional Headers to determine DEP and ASLR

Tags: c++, winapi, portable-executable

I wish to parse a PE file and read the Optional Headers from it, and some other data which enables me to know if it is a 32bit PE or a 64 bit.
I know that imagehlp and dbghlp header files give me structures such as **IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER**.
But I am not sure how to parse my file to yield these. I can use the documentation and write my own parser using offsets, but if anyone knows the correct API to parse the PE?

My objective :
1) determine if the file is x64 or x86 executable. Probably in Header??
2) Check for ASLR, DEP and SAFESEH. the first two I think will be in PE Optional Headers.

So is there any API to parse my PE and return me these structures?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the Image Helper Library. There is a method [`MapAndLoad`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680353.aspx) that will give you a pointer to various parts of the PE file ([`LOADED_IMAGE` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680349.aspx)), i.e. **IMAGE_NT_HEADERS**, **IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER**. The [`IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680336.aspx) contains a pointer to an [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339.aspx).

The field **DllCharacteristic** contains various flags like **IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT** or **IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_SEH** for example.

To use these API include Imagehlp.h and link to Imagehlp.lib.

Comment: Imagehlp.h and DbgHelp.h cannot be included at the same time it seems, because both have same structures defined. Is there some trick to it?

Also, MapAndLoad seems to fail no matter what I do.MapAndLoad(pimagename,pimagepath,pLoadedImage,FALSE,TRUE) fails with 87(invalid parameter), pimagename and pimagepath are PCSTR (char*). False because it is an exe and true because I wish to make it read only. it fails.

Comment: Looks to me as if `Imagehlp.h` is a superset of `DbgHelp.h` so try just including `Imagehlp.h`.

Comment: Yes, @HarryJohnston I reached to this by hit and trial. How did you know that Imagehlp.h is the superset? By reading the file, or is there some tool?

Comment: Yes including Imagehlp.h is indeed enough in order to use this API. @lel: If it fails with error 87, please show us how you call it (what parameters).

Comment: @bkausbk, I am able to run this successfully now. The problem was that my project had the setting "use unicode charset...". I've since rectified this.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) determine if the file is x64 or x86 executable.

`Machine` field from [`IMAGE_FILE_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> 2) Check for ASLR, DEP and SAFESEH

**ASLR**:

- Check `DllCharacteristics` from [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Bitwise AND above field with `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE`: if not 0 then image support ASLR.

**DEP**:

- Check `DllCharacteristics` from [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Bitwise AND above field with `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT`: if not 0 then image support ASLR.

**SAFESEH**:

- Note that SAFESEH is only available for 32-bit PE.
- Go to `DataDirectory` field of [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (array of [`IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
- Get RVA from `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG].VirtualAddress`
- This leads to an [`IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.
- If `SEHandlerTable` field is not 0, then the image supports SAFESEH.

Comment: Hi, I already know how to get the values by using AND with the values. What I wished to know was the API that will parse exe dll ocx etc. Still this is helpful :)